# How to start the timeline when the player enters the trigger area?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have a problem. I want to start the timeline using a script: when the player enters the trigger area (box collider 2d), the timeline starts. But nothing works. I am very new to triggers. I know there is something wrong in my code, but I don't understand how to properly create the condition. Can this be done with a tag? If yes, how to register correctly? Could you help me? I'll be very grateful!

Here is the script code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class TimelineTriggerStarter : MonoBehavior
{
 public string cutsceneKey;
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
 CutsceneManager.Instance.StartCutscene(cutsceneKey);
}
}
```

I used different condition entries, but none of them worked.

I've used different condition entries, but none of them work.

**CutsceneManager** script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CutsceneManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public static CutsceneManager Instance;

    [SerializeField] private List<CutsceneStruct> cutscenes = new List<CutsceneStruct>();

    public static Dictionary<string, GameObject> cutsceneDataBase = new Dictionary<string, GameObject>();

    public static GameObject activeCutscene;

    private void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;

        InitializeCutsceneDataBase();

        foreach (var cutscene in cutsceneDataBase)
        {
            cutscene.Value.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    private void InitializeCutsceneDataBase()
    {
        cutsceneDataBase.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < cutscenes.Count; i++)
        {           
            cutsceneDataBase.Add(cutscenes[i].cutsceneKey, cutscenes[i].cutsceneObject);
        }
    }

    public void StartCutscene(string cutsceneKey)
    {
        if (!cutsceneDataBase.ContainsKey(cutsceneKey)) 
        {
            Debug.LogError($"�������� c ������ \"{cutsceneKey}\" ���� � cutsceneDataBase");
            return;
        } 

        if (activeCutscene != null)
        {
            if (activeCutscene == cutsceneDataBase[cutsceneKey])
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        activeCutscene = cutsceneDataBase[cutsceneKey];

        foreach (var cutscene in cutsceneDataBase)
        {
            cutscene.Value.SetActive(false);
        }

        cutsceneDataBase[cutsceneKey].SetActive(true);
    }

    public void EndCutscene()
    {
        if (activeCutscene != null)
        {
            activeCutscene.SetActive(false);
            activeCutscene = null;
        }
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public struct CutsceneStruct
{
    public string cutsceneKey;
    public GameObject cutsceneObject;
}
```

Comment: Please pay attention to the tags you select. Don't just write a single letter and press the `Enter` key, that will likely select the wrong one. Like the C language tag you have instead of the C#.

Comment: So what aspect doesn't work? The triggering happens, but the timeline doesn't play? Or the triggering never happens? Is the collider set to be a trigger? Does it have a RigidBody?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I fixed this tag

Comment: @Bart, I guess the whole trigger script is uncorrected. I created a BoxCollider2D and added this script to it. But in reality, when the player enters this trigger area, nothing happens - not even errors. Although the timeline should play.
The RigidBody is set for the Player.

Comment: I suggest using a Debug.Log("Player Entered The Trigger"); inside the trigger to know if the trigger isn't working or the timeline isn't starting

Comment: Please provide StartCutscene code. From the code you provided everything seems ok

Comment: @DevAm00 I checked. Trigger not working. Help me please

Comment: @PhillipZoghbi Thanks for commenting. I added the method code to the main question.
I suppose that you need to somehow register the activation condition, but I do not understand how to do it

Comment: Do you have a Playable Director Component on your timeline objects? https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.timeline@1.2/manual/play_director.html

Comment: @PhillipZoghbi yes